# Rails-like Database Migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, refactoring, migration

Is there any easy to install/use (on unix) database migration tools like Rails Migrations? I really like the idea, but installing ruby/rails purely to manage my database migrations seems overkill.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just use ActiveRecord and a simple Rakefile.  For example, if you put your migrations in a `db/migrate` directory and have a `database.yml` file that has your db config, this simple Rakefile should work:

**Rakefile:**

```
require 'active_record'
require 'yaml'

desc "Migrate the database through scripts in db/migrate. Target specific version with VERSION=x"
task :migrate => :environment do
  ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate('db/migrate', ENV["VERSION"] ? ENV["VERSION"].to_i : nil)
end

task :environment do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML::load(File.open('database.yml')))
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
end
```

**database.yml**:

```
adapter: mysql
encoding: utf8
database: test_database
username: root
password:
host: localhost
```

Afterwards, you'll be able to run `rake migrate` and have all the migration goodness without a surrounding rails app.

Alternatively, I have a set of bash scripts that perform a very similar function to ActiveRecord migrations, but they only work with Oracle.  I used to use them before switching to Ruby and Rails.  They are somewhat complicated and I provide no support for them, but if you are interested, feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 4):

There's also a project called [Java Database Migrations](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2008/09/java/java-database-migrations).  To get the code check out the [Google Code page for the project](http://code.google.com/p/c5-db-migration/).

Comment: Looks interesting, but I can't find the download for it?

Comment: Looks as if there's at least the source repository.  I edited the original answer so it's obvious without expanding comments.

Hope that helps.

Comment: "This project currently has no downloads." :(

Answer (score 3):

I see this topic is really old, but I'll chip in for future googlers.

I really like using Python's SQLAlchemy and [SQLAlchemy-Migrate](http://code.google.com/p/sqlalchemy-migrate/)  to manage databases that I need to version control, if you don't want to go the ActiveRecord::Migrate route.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't personally done it, but it should be possible to use ActiveRecord::Migration without any of the other Rails stuff.  Setting up the load path correctly would be the hard part, but really all you need is the `rake` tasks and the `db/migrate` directory plus whatever Rails gems they depend on, probably `activerecord`, `actviesupport` and maybe a couple others like `railties`.  I'd try it and just see what classes are missing and add those in.

At a previous company we built a tool that did essentially what ActiveRecord::Migration does, except it was written in Java as a Maven plugin.  All it did was assemble text blobs of SQL scripts.  It just needs to be smart about the filenames going in order and know how to update a versioning table.

Answer (score 1):

This project is designed to allow active record migrations to be run without installing Rails:

https://github.com/bretweinraub/rails-free-DB-Migrate

Install it (git clone it) and use it as a base for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tool to do this written in Haskell:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dbmigrations