# Do you use source control for your database items?

Tags: database, version-control

I feel that my shop has a hole because we don't have a solid process in place for versioning our database schema changes. We do a lot of backups so we're more or less covered, but it's bad practice to rely on your last line of defense in this way.

Surprisingly, this seems to be a common thread. Many shops I have spoken to ignore this issue because their databases don't change often, and they basically just try to be meticulous.

However, I know how that story goes. It's only a matter of time before things line up just wrong and something goes missing.

Are there any best practices for this? What are some strategies that have worked for you?

Comment: Discussed at the end of Podcast 54. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/podcast-54/

Answer (score 398, accepted):

Must read [Get your database under version control](http://blog.codinghorror.com/get-your-database-under-version-control/). Check the series of posts by K. Scott Allen.

> When it comes to version control, the database is often a second or even third-class citizen. From what I've seen, teams that would never think of writing code without version control in a million years-- and rightly so-- can somehow be completely oblivious to the need for version control around the critical databases their applications rely on. I don't know how you can call yourself a software engineer and maintain a straight face when your database isn't under exactly the same rigorous level of source control as the rest of your code. Don't let this happen to you. Get your database under version control.

Comment: I follow very closely a methodology described in the referenced articles. You don't need to implement every level, and there are variations which will work equally well. The system is flexible, easily customizable, allows for fine-grained control over schema and data changes, and works very well as a best practice for database source control.

The part which can be tricky and adds almost as much security as the rest of the process is a tool to help manage the scripts. It can be as simple as file concatenation, or as complex as automated deployments. First get src ctrl, then think about a tool.

Comment: There's a distributed version control system for databases called [Klonio](https://klonio.com) which is like Git/GitHub for databases.

Answer (score 138):

The databases themselves? No

The scripts that create them, including static data inserts, stored procedures and the like; of course. They're text files, they are included in the project and are checked in and out like everything else.

Of course in an ideal world your database management tool would do this; but you just have to be disciplined about it.

Comment: With Mysql Workbench you can have all that in a structured file(xml) that can be opened and handled with a GUI.

Being xml just text, yes it can be versioning without having to type single sql sentence.

Comment: The database itself is EXACTLY what needs to be under source control, because otherwise it's a manual process to rollback/selectively apply schema changes to match your code-base branch.  If I have three dependent projects, and I switch all of them to a particular branch (e.g. with a particular set of schema migrations), then I should be able to switch my database to that schema as well.  Likewise, it should support merge and rebase operations.  This technology is severely lacking.  Entity framework has no support for a multi-developer environment when it comes to database migrations.

Comment: @Triynko that in practice doesn't work. There's a reason why Microsoft scrapped their database project visual studio type 3+ times. It's because knowing the source and target schema loses all information about schema migrations. If you refactor your schema, an enormous amount of information is blown away. We dropped our attempt to use that model and instead use incremental migration scripts that are carefully crafted to be re-runnable etc so state tolerant.

Comment: I'll note that the discussin Shiv and Tryinko is commonly framed as, "State-based" vs "Migration-based." It's a pretty contentious issue and both approaches have pros and cons.  I'll note that the migration-based approach tends make it faster to create/replace/update a database with the latest migrations, whereas a state-based approach makes actually creating changes.  Which approach is better depends partly on whether you prioritize frequent database changes (use state-based) or frequent deployments to production/test/local/CI (use migration-based).

Comment: As for why Microsoft would use a state-based approach: It's far easier to build tooling/automation for the state-based approach, and it's far more turn-key for developers.  Developers who are currently NOT using version control for their databases will often find the state-based approach more appealing, since it is less disruptive.  Of course, the reason it is less disruptive is that the migration work is pushed from the developers to the release engineers...who will generate a diff script (e.g., via SSDT) and then manually fix it, hoping they didn't miss anything.

Answer (score 39):

I absolutely love Rails ActiveRecord migrations. It abstracts the DML to ruby script which can then be easily version'd in your source repository.

However, with a bit of work, you could do the same thing. Any DDL changes (ALTER TABLE, etc.) can be stored in text files. Keep a numbering system (or a date stamp) for the file names, and apply them in sequence.

Rails also has a 'version' table in the DB that keeps track of the last applied migration. You can do the same easily.

Comment: Completely agreed, current migration version binds to current commit, so you can run rake tasks and keep the system clean and simple process with db changes

Answer (score 34):

Check out [LiquiBase](http://www.liquibase.org) for managing database changes using source control.

Comment: Just to add, [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) is a competing product offering similar functionality that also gets favourable mention on other StackOverflow threads.

Answer (score 30):

You should never just log in and start entering "ALTER TABLE" commands to change a production database.  The project I'm on has database on every customer site, and so every change to the database is made in two places, a dump file that is used to create a new database on a new customer site, and an update file that is run on every update which checks your current database version number against the highest number in the file, and updates your database in place.  So for instance, the last couple of updates:

```
if [ $VERSION \< '8.0.108' ] ; then
  psql -U cosuser $dbName << EOF8.0.108
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    --
    -- Remove foreign key that shouldn't have been there.
    -- PCR:35665
    --
    ALTER TABLE     migratorjobitems
    DROP CONSTRAINT migratorjobitems_destcmaid_fkey;
    -- 
    -- Increment the version
    UPDATE          sys_info
    SET             value = '8.0.108'
    WHERE           key = 'DB VERSION';
    END TRANSACTION;
EOF8.0.108
fi

if [ $VERSION \< '8.0.109' ] ; then
  psql -U cosuser $dbName << EOF8.0.109
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    --
    -- I missed a couple of cases when I changed the legacy playlist
    -- from reporting showplaylistidnum to playlistidnum
    --
    ALTER TABLE     featureidrequestkdcs
    DROP CONSTRAINT featureidrequestkdcs_cosfeatureid_fkey;
    ALTER TABLE     featureidrequestkdcs
    ADD CONSTRAINT  featureidrequestkdcs_cosfeatureid_fkey
    FOREIGN KEY     (cosfeatureid)
    REFERENCES      playlist(playlistidnum)
    ON DELETE       CASCADE;
    --
    ALTER TABLE     ticket_system_ids
    DROP CONSTRAINT ticket_system_ids_showplaylistidnum_fkey;
    ALTER TABLE     ticket_system_ids
    RENAME          showplaylistidnum
    TO              playlistidnum;
    ALTER TABLE     ticket_system_ids
    ADD CONSTRAINT  ticket_system_ids_playlistidnum_fkey
    FOREIGN KEY     (playlistidnum)
    REFERENCES      playlist(playlistidnum)
    ON DELETE       CASCADE;
    -- 
    -- Increment the version
    UPDATE          sys_info
    SET             value = '8.0.109'
    WHERE           key = 'DB VERSION';
    END TRANSACTION;
EOF8.0.109
fi
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but it's worked for me so far.

Comment: We do a similar thing except we put each "if version" in a separate file and have a tool that runs the files in order.

Comment: We're also working on a similar thing, except SQL scripts are installed (new install or upgrade) along with app files, and the location and date and time of script execution are logged.

Comment: I too have written something almost exactly like this, but for Jet (e.g. MS Access) datbases. We're currently using DB Ghost for SQL Server, which does a lot of this for you.

Comment: You can replace `begin transaction; ... end transaction;` with passing `--single-transaction` to `psql`.

Answer (score 20):

Yes.  Code is code.  My rule of thumb is that I need to **be able to build and deploy the application from scratch**, without looking at a development or production machine.

Answer (score 14):

The best practice I have seen is creating a build script to scrap and rebuild your database on a staging server. Each iteration was given a folder for database changes, all changes were scripted with "Drop... Create" 's . This way you can rollback to an earlier version at any time by pointing the build to folder you want to version to.

I believe this was done with NaNt/CruiseControl.

Answer (score 11):

YES, I think it is important to version your database. Not the data, but the schema for certain.

In Ruby On Rails, this is handled by the framework with "migrations". Any time you alter the db, you make a script that applies the changes and check it into source control.

My shop liked that idea so much that we added the functionality to our Java-based build [using shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101868/rails-like-database-migrations#104903) and Ant. We integrated the process into our deployment routine.  It would be fairly easy to write scripts to do the same thing in other frameworks that don't support DB versioning out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 9):

The new Database projects in Visual Studio provide source control and change scripts.

They have a nice tool that compares databases and can generate a script that converts the schema of one into the other, or updates the data in one to match the other.

The db schema is "shredded" to create many, many small .sql files, one per DDL command that describes the DB.

+tom

---

Additional info 2008-11-30

I have been using it as a developer for the past year and really like it.  It makes it easy to compare my dev work to production and generate a script to use for the release.  I don't know if it is missing features that DBAs need for "enterprise-type" projects.

Because the schema is "shredded" into sql files the source control works fine.

One gotcha is that you need to have a different mindset when you use a db project.  The tool has a "db project" in VS, which is just the sql, plus an automatically generated local database which has the schema and some other admin data -- but none of your application data, plus your local dev db that you use for app data dev work.  You rarely are aware of the automatically generated db, but you have to know its there so you can leave it alone :).  This special db is clearly recognizable because it has a Guid in its name,

The VS DB Project does a nice job of integrating db changes that other team members have made into your local project/associated db.  but you need to take the extra step to compare the project schema with your local dev db schema and apply the mods.  It makes sense, but it seems awkward at first.

DB Projects are a very powerful tool.  They not only generate scripts but can apply them immediately.  Be sure not to destroy your production db with it.  ;)

I really like the VS DB projects and I expect to use this tool for all my db projects going forward.

+tom

Answer (score 8):

Requiring the development teams to use an SQL database source control management system isn’t the magic bullet which will prevent issues from happening. On its own, database source control introduces additional overhead as the developers are required to save the changes they’ve made to an object in a separate SQL script, open the source control system client, check in the SQL script file using the client and then apply the changes to the live database.

I can suggest using the SSMS add-in called [ApexSQL Source Control](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_source_control.aspx). It allows developers to easily map database objects with the source control system via the wizard directly from SSMS. The add-in includes support for TFS, Git, Subversion and other SC systems. It also includes support for source controlling Static data.

After downloading and installing ApexSQL Source Control, simply right-click the database you want to version control and navigate to ApexSQL Source Control sub-menu in SSMS. Click the Link database to source control option, select the source control system and the development model. After that you’ll need to provide the log-in information and the repository string for the source control system you’ve chosen.

You can read this article for more information: http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/sql-source-control-reduce-database-development-time/

Answer (score 6):

I do by saving create/update scripts and a script that generates sampledata.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, we do it by keeping our SQL as part of our build -- we keep DROP.sql, CREATE.sql, USERS.sql, VALUES.sql and version control these, so we can revert back to any tagged version.

We also have ant tasks which can recreate the db whenever needed.

Plus, the SQL is then tagged along with your source code that goes with it.

Answer (score 6):

The most successful scheme I've ever used on a project has combined backups and differential SQL files.  Basically we would take a backup of our db after every release and do an SQL dump so that we could create a blank schema from scratch if we needed to as well.  Then anytime you needed to make a change to the DB you would add an alter scrip to the sql directory under version control.  We would always prefix a sequence number or date to the file name so the first change would be something like 01_add_created_on_column.sql, and the next script would be 02_added_customers_index.  Our CI machine would check for these and run them sequentially on a fresh copy of the db that had been restored from the backup.

We also had some scripts in place that devs could use to re-initialize their local db to the current version with a single command.

Answer (score 6):

We do source control all our dabase created objects. And just to keep developers honest (because you can create objects without them being in Source Control), our dbas periodically look for anything not in source control and if they find anything, they drop it without asking if it is ok.

Answer (score 5):

I use [SchemaBank](https://web.archive.org/web/20090721222904/http://schemabank.com/) to version control all my database schema changes:

- from day 1, I import my db schema dump into it
- i started to change my schema design using a web browser (because they are SaaS / cloud-based)
- when i want to update my db server, i generate the change (SQL) script from it and apply to the db. In Schemabank, they mandate me to commit my work as a version before I can generate an update script. I like this kind of practice so that I can always trace back when I need to.

Our team rule is NEVER touch the db server directly without storing the design work first. But it happens, somebody might be tempted to break the rule, in sake of convenient. We would import the schema dump again into schemabank and let it do the diff and bash someone if a discrepancy is found. Although we could generate the alter scripts from it to make our db and schema design in sync, we just hate that.

By the way, they also let us create branches within the version control tree so that I can maintain one for staging and one for production. And one for coding sandbox.

A pretty neat web-based schema design tool with version control n change management.

Answer (score 4):

I have everything necessary to recreate my DB from bare metal, minus the data itself.  I'm sure there are lots of ways to do it, but all my scripts and such are stored off in subversion and we can rebuild the DB structure and such by pulling all that out of subversion and running an installer.

Answer (score 4):

I typically build an SQL script for every change I make, and another to revert those changes, and keep those scripts under version control.

Then we have a means to create a new up-to-date database on demand, and can easily move between revisions. Every time we do a release, we lump the scripts together (takes a bit of manual work, but it's rarely actually *hard*) so we also have a set of scripts that can convert between versions.

Yes, before you say it, this is very similar to the stuff Rails and others do, but it seems to work pretty well, so I have no problems admitting that I shamelessly lifted the idea :)

Answer (score 4):

I use SQL CREATE scripts exported from MySQL Workbech, then using theirs "Export SQL ALTER" functionality I end up with a series of create scripts(numbered of course) and the alter scripts that can apply the changes between them.

> 3.- Export SQL ALTER script
>   Normally you would have to write the ALTER TABLE statements by hand now, reflecting your changes you made to the model. But you can be smart and let Workbench do the hard work for you. Simply select File -> Export -> Forward Engineer SQL ALTER Script… from the main menu.
>
> This will prompt you to specify the SQL CREATE file the current model should be compared to.
>
> Select the SQL CREATE script from step 1. The tool will then generate the ALTER TABLE script for you and you can execute this script against your database to bring it up to date.
>
> You can do this using the MySQL Query Browser or the mysql client.Voila! Your model and database have now been synchronized!

Source: [MySQL Workbench Community Edition: Guide to Schema Synchronization](http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/?p=116)

All this scripts of course are inside under version control.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, always. You should be able to recreate your production database structure with a useful set of sample data whenever needed. If you don't, over time minor changes to keep things running get forgotten then one day you get bitten, big time. Its insurance that you might not think you need but the day you do it it worth the price 10 times over!

Answer (score 4):

There has been a lot of discussion about the database model itself, but we also keep the required data in .SQL files.

For example, in order to be useful your application might need this in the install:

```
INSERT INTO Currency (CurrencyCode, CurrencyName) 
VALUES ('AUD', 'Australian Dollars');

INSERT INTO Currency (CurrencyCode, CurrencyName) 
VALUES ('USD', 'US Dollars');
```

We would have a file called `currency.sql` under subversion.  As a manual step in the build process, we compare the previous currency.sql to the latest one and write an upgrade script.

Comment: We keep the required data in a database (who would have thunk?), then use our tools to generate these insert/update scripts to keep the reference data in sync between dev, qa, production, etc. 

It's so much easier to manage the data and the changes this way.

The scripts are all controlled in by our version/config tools.

Comment: Is this practical when you database has many millions of rows?

Answer (score 4):

We version and source control everything surrounding our databases:

- DDL (create and alters)
- DML (reference data, codes, etc.)
- Data Model changes (using ERwin or ER/Studio)
- Database configuration changes (permissions, security objects, general config changes)

We do all this with automated jobs using Change Manager and some custom scripts.  We have Change Manager monitoring these changes and notifying when they are done.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that every DB should be under source control, and developers should have an easy way to create their local database from scratch.  Inspired by Visual Studio for Database Professionals, I've created an open-source tool that scripts MS SQL databases, and provides and easy way of deploying them to your local DB engine.  Try http://dbsourcetools.codeplex.com/ . Have fun,
- Nathan.

Answer (score 3):

I source control the database schema by scripting out all objects (table definitions, indexes, stored procedures, etc.).  But, as for the data itself, simply rely on regular backups.  This ensures that all structural changes are captured with proper revision history, but doesn't burden the database each time data changes.

Answer (score 3):

At our business we use database change scripts.  When a script is run, it's name is stored in the database and won't run again, unless that row is removed.  Scripts are named based on date, time and code branch, so controlled execution is possible.

Lots and lots of testing is done before the scripts are run in the live environment, so "oopsies" only happen, generally speaking, on development databases.

Answer (score 3):

We're in the process of moving all the databases to source control. We're using sqlcompare to script out the database (a profession edition feature, unfortunately) and putting that result into SVN.

The success of your implementation will depend a lot on the culture and practices of your organization. People here believe in creating a database per application. There is a common set of databases that are used by most applications as well causing a lot of interdatabase dependencies (some of them are circular). Putting the database schemas into source control has been notoriously difficult because of the interdatabase dependencies that our systems have.

Best of luck to you, the sooner you try it out the sooner you'll have your issues sorted out.

Answer (score 3):

I have used the dbdeploy tool from ThoughtWorks at http://dbdeploy.com/. It encourages the use of migration scripts. Each release, we consolidated the change scripts into a single file to ease understanding and to allow DBAs to 'bless' the changes.

Answer (score 3):

This has always been a big annoyance for me too - it seems like it is just way too easy to make a quick change to your development database, save it (forgetting to save a change script), and then you're stuck.  You could undo what you just did and redo it to create the change script, or write it from scratch if you want of course too, though that's a lot of time spent writing scripts.

A tool that I have used in the past that has helped with this some is SQL Delta.  It will show you the differences between two databases (SQL server/Oracle I believe) and generate all the change scripts necessary to migrate A->B.  Another nice thing it does is show all the differences between database content between the production (or test) DB and your development DB.  Since more and more apps store configuration and state that is crucial to their execution in database tables, it can be a real pain to have change scripts that remove, add, and alter the proper rows.  SQL Delta shows the rows in the database just like they would look in a Diff tool - changed, added, deleted.

An excellent tool.  Here is the link:
http://www.sqldelta.com/

Answer (score 3):

RedGate is great, we generate new snapshots when database changes are made (a tiny binary file) and keep that file in the projects as a resource.  Whenever we need to update the database, we use RedGate's toolkit to update the database, as well as being able to create new databases from empty ones.

RedGate also makes Data snapshots, while I haven't personally worked with them, they are just as robust.

Comment: Red Gate's SQL Source Control has been developed to address this problem, so please take a look and let us know if it does or doesn't meet your requirements. The advantage of SQL Source Control above SQL Compare is that it integrates with SSMS and therefore doesn't require a separate tool to be loaded to log different schema versions. [I'm a product manager at Red Gate]

Answer (score 3):

FYI This was also brought up a few days ago by Dana ... [Stored procedures/DB schema in source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77172/stored-proceduresdb-schema-in-source-control#77500)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample poor man's solution for a trigger implementing tracking of changes on db objects ( via DDL stateements ) on a sql server 2005 / 2008 database. I contains also a simple sample of how-to enforce the usage of required someValue  xml tag in the source code for each sql command ran on the database + the tracking of the current db version and type ( dev , test , qa , fb , prod) 
One could extend it with additional required attributes such as  ,  etc. 
The code is rather long - it creates the empty database + the needed tracking table structure + required db functions and the populating trigger all running under a [ga] schema.

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  Database [DBGA_DEV]    Script Date: 04/22/2009 13:22:01 ******/
CREATE DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'DBGA_DEV', FILENAME = N'D:\GENAPP\DATA\DBFILES\DBGA_DEV.mdf' , SIZE = 3072KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'DBGA_DEV_log', FILENAME = N'D:\GENAPP\DATA\DBFILES\DBGA_DEV_log.ldf' , SIZE = 6208KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
GO

IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [DBGA_DEV].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET ANSI_PADDING ON 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET ARITHABORT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET  DISABLE_BROKER 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET  READ_WRITE 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET RECOVERY FULL 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET  MULTI_USER 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DBGA_DEV] SET DB_CHAINING OFF 
GO

EXEC [DBGA_DEV].sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'DbType', @value=N'DEV' 
GO

EXEC [DBGA_DEV].sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'DbVersion', @value=N'0.0.1.20090414.1100' 
GO



USE [DBGA_DEV]
GO
/****** Object:  Schema [ga]    Script Date: 04/22/2009 13:21:29 ******/
CREATE SCHEMA [ga] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Contains the objects of the Generic Application database' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'ga'
GO
/****** Object:  Table [ga].[tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog]    Script Date: 04/22/2009 13:21:40 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [ga].[tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog](
    [LogId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [DatabaseName] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [SchemaName] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [DbVersion] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [DbType] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [EventType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ObjectName] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [ObjectType] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [Version] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SqlCommand] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [EventDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LoginName] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ChangeDescription] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [ObjVersion] [varchar](20) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'The database version as written in the extended prop of the database' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'ga', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'DbVersion'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'dev , test , qa , fb or prod' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'ga', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'DbType'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'The name of the object as it is registered in the sys.objects ' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'ga', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'ObjectName'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'ga', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'Description'
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ga].[tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog] ON
INSERT [ga].[tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog] ([LogId], [DatabaseName], [SchemaName], [DbVersion], [DbType], [EventType], [ObjectName], [ObjectType], [Version], [SqlCommand], [EventDate], [LoginName], [FirstName], [LastName], [ChangeDescription], [Description], [ObjVersion]) VALUES (3, N'DBGA_DEV', N'en', N'0.0.1.20090414.1100', N'DEV', N'DROP_TABLE', N'tb_BL_Products', N'TABLE', N' some', N'<EVENT_INSTANCE><EventType>DROP_TABLE</EventType><PostTime>2009-04-22T11:03:11.880</PostTime><SPID>57</SPID><ServerName>YSG</ServerName><LoginName>ysg\yordgeor</LoginName><UserName>dbo</UserName><DatabaseName>DBGA_DEV</DatabaseName><SchemaName>en</SchemaName><ObjectName>tb_BL_Products</ObjectName><ObjectType>TABLE</ObjectType><TSQLCommand><SetOptions ANSI_NULLS="ON" ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT="ON" ANSI_PADDING="ON" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="ON" ENCRYPTED="FALSE"/><CommandText>drop TABLE [en].[tb_BL_Products] --<Version> some</Version>&#x0D;
</CommandText></TSQLCommand></EVENT_INSTANCE>', CAST(0x00009BF300B6271C AS DateTime), N'ysg\yordgeor', N'Yordan', N'Georgiev', NULL, NULL, N'0.0.0')
INSERT [ga].[tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog] ([LogId], [DatabaseName], [SchemaName], [DbVersion], [DbType], [EventType], [ObjectName], [ObjectType], [Version], [SqlCommand], [EventDate], [LoginName], [FirstName], [LastName], [ChangeDescription], [Description], [ObjVersion]) VALUES (4, N'DBGA_DEV', N'en', N'0.0.1.20090414.1100', N'DEV', N'CREATE_TABLE', N'tb_BL_Products', N'TABLE', N' 2.2.2 ', N'<EVENT_INSTANCE><EventType>CREATE_TABLE</EventType><PostTime>2009-04-22T11:03:18.620</PostTime><SPID>57</SPID><ServerName>YSG</ServerName><LoginName>ysg\yordgeor</LoginName><UserName>dbo</UserName><DatabaseName>DBGA_DEV</DatabaseName><SchemaName>en</SchemaName><ObjectName>tb_BL_Products</ObjectName><ObjectType>TABLE</ObjectType><TSQLCommand><SetOptions ANSI_NULLS="ON" ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT="ON" ANSI_PADDING="ON" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="ON" ENCRYPTED="FALSE"/><CommandText>CREATE TABLE [en].[tb_BL_Products](&#x0D;
    [ProducId] [int] NULL,&#x0D;
    [ProductName] [nchar](10) NULL,&#x0D;
    [ProductDescription] [varchar](5000) NULL&#x0D;
) ON [PRIMARY]&#x0D;
/*&#x0D;
<Version> 2.2.2 </Version>&#x0D;
&#x0D;
*/&#x0D;
</CommandText></TSQLCommand></EVENT_INSTANCE>', CAST(0x00009BF300B62F07 AS DateTime), N'ysg\yordgeor', N'Yordan', N'Georgiev', NULL, NULL, N'0.0.0')
INSERT [ga].[tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog] ([LogId], [DatabaseName], [SchemaName], [DbVersion], [DbType], [EventType], [ObjectName], [ObjectType], [Version], [SqlCommand], [EventDate], [LoginName], [FirstName], [LastName], [ChangeDescription], [Description], [ObjVersion]) VALUES (5, N'DBGA_DEV', N'en', N'0.0.1.20090414.1100', N'DEV', N'DROP_TABLE', N'tb_BL_Products', N'TABLE', N' 2.2.2 ', N'<EVENT_INSTANCE><EventType>DROP_TABLE</EventType><PostTime>2009-04-22T11:25:12.620</PostTime><SPID>57</SPID><ServerName>YSG</ServerName><LoginName>ysg\yordgeor</LoginName><UserName>dbo</UserName><DatabaseName>DBGA_DEV</DatabaseName><SchemaName>en</SchemaName><ObjectName>tb_BL_Products</ObjectName><ObjectType>TABLE</ObjectType><TSQLCommand><SetOptions ANSI_NULLS="ON" ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT="ON" ANSI_PADDING="ON" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="ON" ENCRYPTED="FALSE"/><CommandText>drop TABLE [en].[tb_BL_Products] &#x0D;
</CommandText></TSQLCommand></EVENT_INSTANCE>', CAST(0x00009BF300BC32F1 AS DateTime), N'ysg\yordgeor', N'Yordan', N'Georgiev', NULL, NULL, N'0.0.0')
INSERT [ga].[tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog] ([LogId], [DatabaseName], [SchemaName], [DbVersion], [DbType], [EventType], [ObjectName], [ObjectType], [Version], [SqlCommand], [EventDate], [LoginName], [FirstName], [LastName], [ChangeDescription], [Description], [ObjVersion]) VALUES (6, N'DBGA_DEV', N'en', N'0.0.1.20090414.1100', N'DEV', N'CREATE_TABLE', N'tb_BL_Products', N'TABLE', N' 2.2.2 ', N'<EVENT_INSTANCE><EventType>CREATE_TABLE</EventType><PostTime>2009-04-22T11:25:19.053</PostTime><SPID>57</SPID><ServerName>YSG</ServerName><LoginName>ysg\yordgeor</LoginName><UserName>dbo</UserName><DatabaseName>DBGA_DEV</DatabaseName><SchemaName>en</SchemaName><ObjectName>tb_BL_Products</ObjectName><ObjectType>TABLE</ObjectType><TSQLCommand><SetOptions ANSI_NULLS="ON" ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT="ON" ANSI_PADDING="ON" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="ON" ENCRYPTED="FALSE"/><CommandText>CREATE TABLE [en].[tb_BL_Products](&#x0D;
    [ProducId] [int] NULL,&#x0D;
    [ProductName] [nchar](10) NULL,&#x0D;
    [ProductDescription] [varchar](5000) NULL&#x0D;
) ON [PRIMARY]&#x0D;
/*&#x0D;
<Version> 2.2.2 </Version>&#x0D;
&#x0D;
*/&#x0D;
</CommandText></TSQLCommand></EVENT_INSTANCE>', CAST(0x00009BF300BC3A69 AS DateTime), N'ysg\yordgeor', N'Yordan', N'Georgiev', NULL, NULL, N'0.0.0')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ga].[tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog] OFF
/****** Object:  Table [ga].[tb_BLSec_LoginsForUsers]    Script Date: 04/22/2009 13:21:40 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [ga].[tb_BLSec_LoginsForUsers](
    [LoginsForUsersId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LoginName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [SecondName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [DomainName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ga].[tb_BLSec_LoginsForUsers] ON
INSERT [ga].[tb_BLSec_LoginsForUsers] ([LoginsForUsersId], [LoginName], [FirstName], [SecondName], [LastName], [DomainName]) VALUES (1, N'ysg\yordgeor', N'Yordan', N'Stanchev', N'Georgiev', N'yordgeor')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ga].[tb_BLSec_LoginsForUsers] OFF
/****** Object:  Table [en].[tb_BL_Products]    Script Date: 04/22/2009 13:21:40 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [en].[tb_BL_Products](
    [ProducId] [int] NULL,
    [ProductName] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [ProductDescription] [varchar](5000) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [ga].[procUtils_SqlCheatSheet]    Script Date: 04/22/2009 13:21:37 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [ga].[procUtils_SqlCheatSheet]                

as                 
set nocount on                 

--what was the name of the table with something like role                
/*                
SELECT * from sys.tables where [name] like '%POC%'                
*/                
-- what are the columns of this table                 
/*                
select column_name , DATA_TYPE , CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,  table_name  from Information_schema.columns where table_name='tbGui_ExecutePOC'                
*/                

-- find proc        
--what was the name of procedure with something like role                
/*                
select * from sys.procedures where [name] like '%ext%'                
exec sp_HelpText procName        
*/                
/*                
exec sp_helpText procUtils_InsertGenerator                
*/                
--how to list all databases in sql server                 
/*                
SELECT database_id AS ID, NULL AS ParentID, name AS Text FROM sys.databases ORDER BY [name]                
*/                

--HOW-TO LIST ALL TABLES IN A SQL SERVER 2005 DATABASE                
/*                
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM [POC].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES                
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'                  
AND TABLE_NAME <> 'dtproperties'                  
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME                


*/                
--HOW-TO ENABLE XP_CMDSHELL START                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------                
-- configure verbose mode temporarily                 
-- EXECUTE sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1                 
-- RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE                 
--GO                 


--ENABLE xp_cmdshell                 
-- EXECUTE sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', '1'                 
-- RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE                 
-- EXEC SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced option', '1';                 
-- SHOW THE CONFIGURATION                 
-- EXEC SP_CONFIGURE;                 


--turn show advance options off                 
-- GO                 
--EXECUTE sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0                 
-- RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE                 
-- GO                

--HOW-TO ENABLE XP_CMDSHELL END                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------                

--HOW-TO IMPLEMENT SLEEP                 
-- sleep for 10 seconds                 
-- WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10' SELECT * FROM My_Table                

/* LIST ALL PRIMARY KEYS                 

SELECT                 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_NAME AS TABLE_NAME,                
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.COLUMN_NAME AS COLUMN_NAME,                 
  REPLACE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_TYPE,' ', '_') AS CONSTRAINT_TYPE                 
FROM                 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS                 
  INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ON                 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_NAME =                 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE.CONSTRAINT_NAME                 
WHERE                 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_NAME <> N'sysdiagrams'                 
ORDER BY                 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_NAME ASC                

*/                

--HOW-TO COPY TABLE AND THE WHOLE TABLE DATA , COPY TABLE FROM DB TO DB                
--==================================================START                 
/*                
use Poc_Dev                
go                
drop table tbGui_LinksVisibility                

use POc_test                
go                
select *                 
INTO [POC_Dev].[ga].[tbGui_LinksVisibility]                
from [POC_TEST].[ga].[tbGui_LinksVisibility]                


*/                
--HOW-TO COPY TABLE AND THE WHOLE TABLE DATA , COPY TABLE FROM DB TO DB                
--====================================================END                
--=================================================== SEE TABLE METADATA START                
/*                



SELECT c.name AS [COLUMN_NAME], sc.data_type AS [DATA_TYPE], [value] AS                 
[DESCRIPTION] , c.max_length as [MAX_LENGTH] , c.is_nullable AS [OPTIONAL]                 
, c.is_identity AS [IS_PRIMARY_KEY] FROM sys.extended_properties AS ep                 
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON ep.major_id = t.object_id                 
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON ep.major_id = c.object_id AND ep.minor_id                 
= c.column_id                 
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS sc ON t.name = sc.table_name and                 
c.name = sc.column_name                 
WHERE class = 1 and t.name = 'tbGui_ExecutePOC' ORDER BY SC.DATA_TYPE                


*/                
--=================================================== SEE TABLE METADATA END               
    /*            
select * from Information_schema.columns                
select table_name , column_name from Information_schema.columns where table_name='tbGui_Wizards'                
    */            


--=================================================== LIST ALL TABLES AND THEIR DESCRIPTOINS START                
/*                

SELECT T.name AS TableName, CAST(Props.value AS varchar(1000)) AS                
TableDescription                
FROM sys.tables AS T LEFT OUTER JOIN                
(SELECT class, class_desc, major_id, minor_id,                
name, value                
FROM sys.extended_properties                
WHERE (minor_id = 0) AND (class = 1)) AS                
Props ON T.object_id = Props.major_id                
WHERE (T.type = 'U') AND (T.name <> N'sysdiagrams')                
ORDER BY TableName                
*/                
--=================================================== LIST ALL TABLES AND THEIR DESCRIPTOINS START                

--=================================================== LIST ALL OBJECTS FROM DB START                
/*                


use DB                
--HOW-TO LIST ALL PROCEDURE IN A DATABASE                
select s.name from sysobjects s where type = 'P'                
--HOW-TO LIST ALL TRIGGERS BY NAME IN A DATABASE                
select s.name from sysobjects s where type = 'TR'                
--HOW-TO LIST TABLES IN A DATABASE                 
select s.name from sysobjects s where type = 'U'                
--how-to list all system tables in a database                
select s.name from sysobjects s where type = 's'                
--how-to list all the views in a database                
select s.name from sysobjects s where type = 'v'                


*/                

/*                
Similarly you can find out other objects created by user, simple change type =                 

C = CHECK constraint                 

D = Default or DEFAULT constraint                 

F = FOREIGN KEY constraint                 

L = Log                 

FN = Scalar function                 

IF = In-lined table-function                 

P = Stored procedure                 

PK = PRIMARY KEY constraint (type is K)                 

RF = Replication filter stored procedure                

S = System table                 

TF = Table function                 

TR = Trigger                 

U = User table ( this is the one I discussed above in the example)                

UQ = UNIQUE constraint (type is K)                 

V = View                 

X = Extended stored procedure                
*/                



--=================================================== HOW-TO SEE ALL MY PERMISSIONS START                


/*                

SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER');                
USE poc_qa;                
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'database');                
GO                

*/                
--=================================================== HOW-TO SEE ALL MY PERMISSIONS END                

/*               
--find table               

use poc_dev               
go               
select s.name from sysobjects s where type = 'u'  and s.name like '%Visibility%'              
select * from tbGui_LinksVisibility              

*/              

/* find cursor              

use poc      
go        
DECLARE @procName varchar(100)        
DECLARE @cursorProcNames CURSOR        
SET @cursorProcNames = CURSOR FOR        
select name from sys.procedures where modify_date > '2009-02-05 13:12:15.273' order by modify_date desc       

OPEN @cursorProcNames        
FETCH NEXT        
FROM @cursorProcNames INTO @procName        
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0        
BEGIN        

set nocount off;        
exec sp_HelpText @procName --- or print them        
-- print @procName        

FETCH NEXT        
FROM @cursorProcNames INTO @procName        
END        
CLOSE @cursorProcNames        

select @@error    

*/              


/* --  SEE STORED PROCEDURE EXT PROPS            

SELECT ep.name as 'EXT_PROP_NAME' , SP.NAME , [value] as 'DESCRIPTION' FROM sys.extended_properties as ep left join sys.procedures as sp on sp.object_id = ep.major_id where sp.type='P'            


-- what the hell I ve been doing lately on sql server 2005 / 2008
select o.name , 
(SELECT [definition] AS [text()] FROM sys.all_sql_modules where sys.all_sql_modules.object_id=a.object_id FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS Statement_Text
, a.object_id, o.modify_date from sys.all_sql_modules a left join sys.objects o on a.object_id=o.object_id order by 4 desc



-- GET THE RIGHT LANG SCHEMA START 
DECLARE @template AS varchar(max)
SET @template = 'SELECT * FROM {object_name}'

DECLARE @object_name AS sysname

SELECT @object_name = QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name)
FROM sys.objects o
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s
    ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
WHERE o.object_id = OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(@LANG) + '.[TestingLanguagesInNameSpacesDelMe]')

IF @object_name IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql AS varchar(max)
    SET @sql = REPLACE(@template, '{object_name}', @object_name)
    EXEC (@sql)
END
-- GET THE RIGHT LANG SCHEMA END 

--  SEE STORED PROCEDURE EXT PROPS end*/             
set nocount off
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuthorName', @value=N'Yordan Georgiev' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'ga', @level1type=N'PROCEDURE',@level1name=N'procUtils_SqlCheatSheet'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'ProcDescription', @value=N'TODO:ADD HERE DESCRPIPTION' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'ga', @level1type=N'PROCEDURE',@level1name=N'procUtils_SqlCheatSheet'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'ProcVersion', @value=N'0.1.0.20090406.1317' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'ga', @level1type=N'PROCEDURE',@level1name=N'procUtils_SqlCheatSheet'
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [ga].[GetDbVersion]    Script Date: 04/22/2009 13:21:42 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [ga].[GetDbVersion]()
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
    BEGIN
        RETURN convert(varchar(20) , (select value from sys.extended_properties where name='DbVersion' and class_desc='DATABASE') )
    END
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AuthorName', @value=N'Yordan Georgiev' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'ga', @level1type=N'FUNCTION',@level1name=N'GetDbVersion'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'ChangeDescription', @value=N'Initial creation' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'ga', @level1type=N'FUNCTION',@level1name=N'GetDbVersion'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'CreatedWhen', @value=N'getDate()' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'ga', @level1type=N'FUNCTION',@level1name=N'GetDbVersion'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'Description', @value=N'Gets the current version of the database ' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'ga', @level1type=N'FUNCTION',@level1name=N'GetDbVersion'
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [ga].[GetDbType]    Script Date: 04/22/2009 13:21:42 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [ga].[GetDbType]()
RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
    BEGIN
        RETURN convert(varchar(30) , (select value from sys.extended_properties where name='DbType' and class_desc='DATABASE') )
    END
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog_DbVersion]    Script Date: 04/22/2009 13:21:40 ******/
ALTER TABLE [ga].[tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog_DbVersion]  DEFAULT ('select ga.GetDbVersion()') FOR [DbVersion]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog_EventDate]    Script Date: 04/22/2009 13:21:40 ******/
ALTER TABLE [ga].[tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog_EventDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [EventDate]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog_ObjVersion]    Script Date: 04/22/2009 13:21:40 ******/
ALTER TABLE [ga].[tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog_ObjVersion]  DEFAULT ('0.0.0') FOR [ObjVersion]
GO
/****** Object:  DdlTrigger [trigMetaDoc_TraceDbChanges]    Script Date: 04/22/2009 13:21:29 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create trigger [trigMetaDoc_TraceDbChanges]
on database
for create_procedure, alter_procedure, drop_procedure,
create_table, alter_table, drop_table,
create_function, alter_function, drop_function , 
create_trigger , alter_trigger , drop_trigger 
as

set nocount on

declare @data xml
set @data = EVENTDATA()
declare @DbVersion varchar(20)
set @DbVersion =(select ga.GetDbVersion())
declare @DbType varchar(20)
set @DbType =(select ga.GetDbType())
declare @DbName varchar(256)
set @DbName =@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)[1]', 'varchar(256)')
declare @EventType varchar(256)
set @EventType =@data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
declare @ObjectName varchar(256)
set @ObjectName  = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'varchar(256)')
declare @ObjectType varchar(25)
set @ObjectType = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]', 'varchar(25)')
declare @TSQLCommand varchar(max)
set @TSQLCommand = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
declare @opentag varchar(4)
set @opentag= '&lt;'
declare @closetag varchar(4) 
set @closetag= '&gt;'
declare @newDataTxt varchar(max) 
set @newDataTxt= cast(@data as varchar(max))
set @newDataTxt = REPLACE ( REPLACE(@newDataTxt , @opentag , '<') , @closetag , '>')
-- print @newDataTxt
declare @newDataXml xml 
set @newDataXml = CONVERT ( xml , @newDataTxt)
declare @Version varchar(50)
set @Version = @newDataXml.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText/Version)[1]', 'varchar(50)')

-- if we are dropping take the version from the existing object 
if  ( SUBSTRING(@EventType , 0 , 5)) = 'DROP'
set @Version =( select top 1 [Version]  from ga.tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog where ObjectName=@ObjectName order by [LogId] desc)



declare @LoginName varchar(256) 
set @LoginName = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'varchar(256)')
declare @FirstName varchar(50)
set @FirstName= (select [FirstName] from [ga].[tb_BLSec_LoginsForUsers] where [LoginName] = @LoginName)
declare @LastName varchar(50)
set @LastName  = (select [LastName] from [ga].[tb_BLSec_LoginsForUsers] where [LoginName] = @LoginName)
declare @SchemaName sysname 
set @SchemaName = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]', 'sysname');
--declare @Description xml 
--set @Description = @data.query('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/text())')




--print 'VERSION IS ' + @Version
--print @newDataTxt
--print cast(@data as varchar(max))


-- select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name ='tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog'
insert into [ga].[tb_DataMeta_ObjChangeLog]
(
[DatabaseName] ,
[SchemaName],
[DbVersion] ,
[DbType],
[EventType],
[ObjectName],
[ObjectType] ,
[Version],
[SqlCommand] ,
[LoginName] ,
[FirstName],
[LastName] 
)

values(

@DbName,
@SchemaName,
@DbVersion,
@DbType,
@EventType, 
@ObjectName, 
@ObjectType , 
@Version,
@newDataTxt, 
@LoginName , 
@FirstName , 
@LastName
)
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
DISABLE TRIGGER [trigMetaDoc_TraceDbChanges] ON DATABASE
GO
/****** Object:  DdlTrigger [trigMetaDoc_TraceDbChanges]    Script Date: 04/22/2009 13:21:29 ******/
Enable Trigger [trigMetaDoc_TraceDbChanges] ON Database
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

[Flyway](https://www.red-gate.com/products/flyway/editions) provides object level database versioning in its Teams and Enterprise tiers.

Flyway provides both a state-based development experience as well as a migrations-based deployment capability.

Flyway extends the concepts in SQL Source Control (which was SQL Server only) and adds the option to deploy using migration scripts, as well as taking it cross-database.

Comment: I would not recommend Red-Gate's product to anyone. I have been using SQL Source Control 2.2 for some time. Actually soon they released version 3. After that they ended up any support for 2.2. Not even they fixed any bugs (which I do not consider new features - bugs are bugs), they also did not include support for TFS2012 when it was released. My company switched from TFS2010 to TFS2012, and we could not connect to TFS anymore. We literally had to throw away Red Gate's software, because the only option they gave us was to buy new version of their software. No plans to update ver. 2.2.

Comment: Wish they had CLI support for non-microsoft operating systems.

Comment: looks like they have a couple tools for MySQL https://www.red-gate.com/products/mysql/mysql-comparison-bundle/

Answer (score 3):

While this question has many good answers, most of them don’t include the innovations changes in the market, specifically with commercial tools.

Here is a short list of tools that do database version control, I listed the pros and cons of each (full discloser: I work for DBmaestro)

Red-Gate – has been on the market for many years. It provides version control of database objects using scripts integrated with file-based version control.

DBVS – provides version control of the database objects using scripts integrated with file-based version control.

DBmaestro – Provides an enforcement of the version control processes (check-out / check-in) on the real database objects. So there is no question if the version control repository is in-sync with the database being used by the application.

I would encourage you to read a comprehensive, unbiased review on Database Enforced Change Management solutions by veteran database expert Ben Taylor which he posted on LinkedIn https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/article/20140907002729-287832-solve-database-change-mangement-with-dbmaestro

Answer (score 2):

Yes ... our databases are designed in ERwin and the DDLs for each version are automatically generated.  The ERwin files are kept in our source code control system (actually, so are our engineering documents).

Answer (score 2):

We use replication and clustering to manage our databases, as well as backups. We use Serena to manage our SQL scripts and configuration implementations. Before a configuration change is made, we perform a backup as part of the change management process. This backup satisfies our rollback requirement.

I think it all depends on scale. Are you talking about enterprise applications that need offsite backups and disaster recovery? A small workgroup running an accounting application? Or everywhere in between?

Answer (score 2):

We have our Create/Alter scripts under source control. As for the database itself, when you have hundreds of tables and a lot of processing data every minutes, it would be CPU and HDD killer to version all the database. That's why backup is still, according to me, the best way to control your data.

Answer (score 2):

I always check my database structure dumps into source control.  Full database dumps however I normally just compress and put away for storage.

Answer (score 2):

My team versions our database schema as C# classes with the rest of our code.  We have a homegrown C# program (<500 lines of code) that reflects the classes and creates SQL commands to build, drop and update the database.  After creating the database we run sqlmetal to generate a linq mapping, which is then compiled in another project that is used to generate test data.  The whole things works really well because data access is checked at compile time.  We like it because the schema is stored in a .cs file which is easy to track compare in trac/svn.

Answer (score 2):

RedGate software makes some great tools that will help you version your database.  Be sure to try to have your devs build their own isolated local databases for dev work rather than rely on a "dev server" which may or may not be down at some time.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words about our software. We've just released SQL Source Control, which makes it even easier to shared changes amongst isolated development databases. I hope you get a chance to try this out and let me know if this works for you. This assumes you're using TFS or SVN.

Answer (score 2):

I have used RedGate SQL Compare Pro for schema synchronization with script folder, then I commit all my update to version control. It works great.

Answer (score 2):

"[Short version: dump your production database into a git repository for an instant backup solution.](http://www.viget.com/extend/backup-your-database-in-git/)"

Answer (score 2):

I've started working on [sqlHawk](http://timabell.github.com/sqlHawk/) which is aimed at providing (open source) tooling around this problem.

It's currently in fairly early stages, but does already support storing and enforcing [stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370011/how-to-add-stored-procedures-to-version-control) and running scripted updates.

I'd be grateful for any input from anyone who has the time to look at this tool.

Apologies for blatant self promotion, but I hope this is useful to someone!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with many of the posting concerning ruby's ActiveRecord migrations - they are an elegant way to manage the database in small incremental files that everyone can share.  With that said, I've recently implemented a project using VisualStudio's Database Project, and it's kinda made me a believer.  Short story - you create a database project, import all (if any) existing database objects into it (tables/views/triggers/keys/users/etc).  That import results in a "Create" script per object.  To manage the database you alter the create script and then on deploy VS compares the target database to the state of the database residing in your project and apply the proper alter statements.

It really is a bit of magic and I have to admit, it's one of the better things the VS team has done.  I'm really impressed up to this point.

Of course, you can manage the whole database project in the version control system of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, so many answers. For solid database versioning you need to version control the code that changes your database. Some CMS offer configuration management tools, such as the one in Drupal 8. Here is an overview with practical steps to [arrange your workflow and ensure the database configuration is versioned](https://ivan.grynenko.com/how-to-version-control-database/), even in team environments:

Answer (score 1):

We have a weekly sql dump into a subversion repo. It's fully automated but it's a REALLY beefy task.

You'll want to limit the number of revisions because it really chows disk space after a while!

Answer (score 1):

I version control the create script, and I use the svn version tag within it. Then, whenever I get a version that is going to be used, I create a script in a dbpatches/ directory named as the version to roll up to. The job of that script is to modify a current database without destroying the data. dbpatches/, for example, might have files named 201, 220, and 240. If the database is currently at level 201, apply patch 220, then patch 240.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `meta`;
CREATE TABLE `meta` (
  `property` varchar(255),
  `value` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`property`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `meta` VALUES ('version', '$Rev: 240 $');
```

Don't forget to test your code before considering a patch good. Caveat emptor!

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, we keep all of our object code (stored procedures, views, triggers, functions, etc.) in source control because these objects are code, and as about every other answer here agrees, code belongs in some form of version control system.

As for CREATE, DROP, ALTER statements, etc. (DDL), we developed and use [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/downloads/buildmaster) to manage the deployment of these scripts such that they can be run once and only once against a target database (whether they fail or not). The general idea is that developers will upload change scripts into the system and when it comes time for deployment, only the change scripts that haven't been run against the target environment's database will be run (this is managed very similarly to [Autocracy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/115885/44765)). The reason for this separation of script types lies in that once you manipulate a table's structure, add an index, etc., you effectively cannot undo that without writing a brand new script, or restoring the database - as opposed to the object code where you can simply drop a view or stored procedure then recreate it.

Some of the benefits can be seen when, for example, you restore your production database into your integration environment, the system automatically knows exactly which scripts haven't been run and will alter the table structure of that newly restored database to be current with regards to development.

Answer (score 0):

We insist upon change scrips and a master data definition script.  These are checked into CVS along with any other source code.  The PL/SQL (were are an Oracle shop) is also source controlled in CVS.  The change scripts are repeatable and can be passed to everyone on the team.  Basically, just because it is a database, there is never an excuse not to code it and use a source control system to track the changes.

Answer (score 0):

We maintain DDL (and sometime DML) scripts generated by our ER Tool (PowerAMC).

We have a bench of shell scripts which rename the scripts starting with a number on the trunk branch.
Each script is committed and tagged with the bugzilla number.

These scripts are then at need merged within the release branches along with the application code.

We have a table recording the scripts and their status.
Each script is executed in order and recorded in this table on each install by the deploying tool.

Answer (score 0):

Your project team can have a DBA to whom every developer would forward their create alter, delete, insert/update (for master data) sql statements. DBAs would run those queries and on successfully making the required update would add those statements to a text file or a spreadsheet. Each addition can be labeled as a savepoint. Incase you revert back to a particular savepoint, just do a drop all and run the queries uptil the labelled savepoint. This approach is just a thought... a bit of fine tuning here would work for your development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Any database interface code absolutely should go into version control (Stored Procedures, Functions, etc).

For structure and data, it is a judgement call.  I personally keep a clean structural template of my databases around, but don't store them in version control, due to the size.  But storing it in version control can be very beneficial, even for just having a history.

Answer (score 0):

A big problem, often overlooked, is that for larger web based systems, it is required to have a transitional period or bucket testing approach to making new releases. This makes it essential to have both rollback and a mechanism for supporting both the old and new schema in the same DB. This requires a scaffolding approach (made populist by the Agile DB folks). In this scenario, lack of process in DB source control can be a total disaster. You need old schema scripts, new schema scripts and a set of intermediate scripts, as well as a tidy up, once the system is fully on the new version (or rolled back).

Rather than having scripts to recreate schema from scratch, what is required is a state based approach, where you need scripts purely to move the DB into the state you require, both forward and back, from version to version. Your DB becomes a series of state scripts, which can be easily source controlled and tagged along with the rest of the source.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. We generate dumps of our PostgreSQL schemas whenever there's a change and check it in. It's already saved us many times, and I've only been at my job a few months.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I've seen more than one team developing PL/SQL programs (stored procedures in Oracle) - sometimes ten thousands LOC - just by editing the code in TOAD (a database tool), without even saving the source to files (except for deployment). Even if the database is backuped regulary (wouldn't take that for granted, though), the only way to retrieve an old version of a stored procedure is to restore the whole database, which is many GB large. And of course sometimes concurrent changes in one file lead to loss of work, when more than one developer works on the same project.

Answer (score 0):

I use ActiveRecord Migrations.  This Ruby gem can be used outside of a Rails project and there are adapters to handle most databases you'll come across.  My tip: if you are able to run your project off Postgres, you get transactional schema migrations.  That means you don't end up with a broken database if a migration only half-applies.

Answer (score 0):

One of Kira's prime use cases is database upgrades by explicitly specify the schema outside the database as code. It then can manage the database and upgrade it to any version from any version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we source control our sql scripts too with subversion. It's a good practice and you can recreate the schema with default data whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

For oracle I use self-written java programm [oracle-ddl2svn](http://oracle-ddl2svn.googlecode.com/) for auto track changes of oracle DDL scheme in SVN

Answer (score 0):

I've heard people say you absolutely have to keep your schemas in the database. I'm not sure I agree. This really depends on the system you're working with. If your system is relatively small and the data is not terribly important. And the the speed at which you need to bring another development environment online is crucial.. then yes.. you can benefit from it. However when your schema is useless without the data and the database is extremely large, it becomes virtually impossible to "source control" your database. Sure, you can still keep your DDL code in source control but that's essentially useless. You can't get the data needed without backup/restore.

In larger database development efforts, I've found backup and restore as the preferred rollback option. Sure you can keep procs, views, functions etc in source control but keeping table.sql is not necessary. Also, if your deployment process is airtight, you'll most likely never have to "rollback" your production environment.