# Need good scheme/workflow for managing database objects using Subversion

Tags: sql-server, database, svn, stored-procedures

How do you track/manage your stored procedures, views, and functions in SQL Server?

I'd like to use Subversion, but it looks like I would have to just save & commit the CREATE/ALTER statements. That might work okay for me, but I suspect I'd end up doing a lot of nagging.

**Is anyone using versioning with their databases? Is there a better way?**

In the past, people have just commented out parts of the code and left it in. Or, they add little "added on 2/31/2010" comments all over. It drives me nuts, because I know there is a better way.

We do log changes in the object's header, but that's pretty limited. It would make my life easier to be able to diff versions.

**Additional Info**
We are using SQL Server 2005. I have Subversion (via VisualSVN Server) and TortoiseSVN installed, but I'm open to other suggestions.

By database objects, I specifically mean stored procedures, views, and functions.

There are only a few tables I would need to track. The database is the backend for a commercial application, and we mostly pull information out for reporting

I found a related question about [stored procedure versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183148/stored-procedure-versioning)

Comment: I'm almost willing to be this has been asked before, but my search mojo is not up to par today. Regardless, this is an excellent question that I also have interest in hearing from the other users.

Comment: I tried searching stackoverflow first, but I didn't find anything either. Didn't find much using Google except for a blog post explaining how to integrate TortoiseSVN with SQL Server Managerment Studio (which was helpful... but I'm trying to figure out a good system for all this, now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We script everything and put it into Subversion. Nothing can be loaded to Prod without a script (developers do not have rights to prod) and the people with rights on prod only accept scripts they loaded from Subversion.

Comment: This might solve a big part of my problem... maybe I should serve as the "gatekeeper" and only update SPs after the changes are committed (via the repository)

Comment: We use a similar system, but I feel myself yearning for something that lets me easily see the history of an sp, table, view etc, just like you can for source files.

Comment: Subversion has a history. I look up past versions all the time.

Answer (score 1):

We revision our database, schema creation, dw, etl, stored procedures just like any other piece of code, because it's code!

I have also seen people type dates in headers, etc. This is normally due to them completely missing the point of revision control.

Comment: How do you implement the revision control?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at liquibase, [here](http://liquibase.org)

It manages your sql changes/scripts for you, and can apply them in conjunction with svn via hooks or scripts. Makes doing all sorts of setup easy, and helps eliminate the case of the missing trigger/sproc/etc...

Comment: I checked out the Liquibase videos, and it looks pretty interesting. Don't like the idea of using a whole other system and syntax (XML) to manage the database, though... especially since the other people who periodically update the procedures/functions/views don't really grok SQL

Comment: Basically, the xml can be ignored, it just wraps the raw SQL in the case of sprocs/triggers and so on, so really they just edit the meat which remains SQL and ignore the rest, xml decoration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you all mean with "database objects". Are these only the tables, views, procedures etc or also data? I mean daily created data?

Assumed you mean the database schema definition. By my experience there is only one way to handle database schema definitions (if you don't have NHibernate or some similar tool). You write sql scripts that create your database from scratch and check them in. You use the same scripts for installation of your software. You see the differences by just comparing the scripts files.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've gone through this excercise, it's come down to 3 main things that need to be source-controlled:

1. Stored Procedures / Views / Triggers (more or less anything that can be fairly expressed as "code". These are fairly simple, include a conditional drop and create at the top of the file.
2. Table Schema - DROP / CREATE statements as above. You can try to get fancy with ALTER statements, but it tends to get really messy.

The biggest challenge we faced was this forces you into a system where your DB goes back to an initial state often - if there's a fair amount of work involved in bringing DBs to something usable / testable, it can be a pain. In that case we kept a library of scripts that brought a DB to various usable states, and source controlled those as well.

3. Data within tables. We looked at a couple of approaches here - either a series of INSERT statements stored in a file like "TableName_Data.sql" or a CSV file with custom build tooling that parsed and inserted when the DB was rebuilt.

Ultimately we went with the INSERT statements for simplicity's sake.