# Saving SQL in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to have Visual Studio 2010 save the SQL you've developed in the SQL Editor to the current solution?

Comment: As some text file in the solution I'm guessing or a stored procedure. I'm not sure what is available which is why I'm venturing the question.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146543/what-is-the-best-way-to-version-control-my-sql-server-stored-procedures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a query via the "Server Explorer" you wont be able to save it. You have to copy the SQL to a file and save it.

You can add a sql file to any project though - there is no out of the box template for them though. So either create a template yourself, or just add a text file and change the extension to .sql - you get syntax highlighting etc but you don't get the 'visual' designer, you'll have to paste your code into a sever explorer, new query :-(

To me there seem to be quite a few issues with what they've tried to do with DBs and Visual Studio 2010. The Database Project is way way over the top for most SQL work.