# Would it make sense to use Git for this project?

Tags: database, svn, git, version-control

We have a project where 99% of the code is PL/SQL, including the front end (Oracle forms). All 10 developers use the same DB instance for developement. The project is big (thousands of DB objects) so there is rarely any contention and any that exist is serialized by locking objects in Subversion before making any changes to them in DB (this is manual and not automated).

Would it make sense to use Git or some other distributed VCS in this situation?

My current thoughts are that it would not, as all changes affect all other developers immediately, even before they are commited in SVN.

Comment: Related: [Do you source control your databases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115369/do-you-source-control-your-databases)

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is no.

I love DVCSs because of it dynamic nature: I can do changes here, commit, there, commit, merge one to another, make changes to it, commit, and only after that finally merge new changes to the “tunk” so that other will see them and will be affected by them.

In your situation *developers use the same DB instance for development*. So any changes affect all other even *before* the code is committed. So I see no point in using D (Distributed) features of VCS in your case.

Comment: On the other hand, git does give you a nice "undo stack" for local changes until you're prepared to push the change to upstream.