# Database change management

Tags: mysql, database, database-management

I was wondering if there is any tool which would help me transfer changes form one database to another. Currently every time I want to deploy new version for tests I have to manually execute all database changes scripts and transfer them to every other database. Is there any way to somehow automate this process ? If it matters , the project is being written in c# and database is MySql

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115369/do-you-use-source-control-for-your-database-items and https://github.com/timabell/sqlHawk/wiki/Further-reading

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a GUI application then Navicat Premium can help you achieve this just.  It has data sync tool and transfer tool and can also work with all major databases.  Only problem is that its not free.

[Navicat Premium](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_premium/premium_overview.html)

Comment: Do You happen to know any freeware application for that ? :)

Comment: @Berial Not really... since I used it never looked for any freeware versions.  But its really worth it since it supports MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQLite and SQL Server you wont need anything else.