# How does MySQL compute keys for underlying tree structure

Tags: sql, mysql, relational-database, b-tree

I have read in a few places that MySQL is based on b-trees, among other data structures, allowing for consistent reads/writes/deletes. As a tree structure would store data based on a given key, I am curious, what is used as the key for the main b-tree structure? Is it just a hash of the table's primary key, or is there a more advanced process to compute the key associated with a given record?

My assumption was that it would be based on the primary key, as this is likely what would be used to identify a given record/row, but I haven't been able to find a definitive answer.

EDIT: This was marked as a duplicate of another question, but it is actually different. I am not asking how adding indexes works, I am asking how the general structure of a SQL database is set up BEFORE any manual indexes are placed on the table. When the table is created, how is each row stored/what is used to store it? It would seem that any query using a JOIN or asking for conditions on a field other than the primary key would take O(N) (linear) time if the key was based solely on a primary key. My research indicates that it is indexing only on primary key by default, but wanted to see if there are other data structures/ways it speeds up queries to avoid linear scans (without manual action to add indexes or other features to the db)

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10378693/how-does-mysql-store-data https://stackoverflow.com/q/16953638/how-is-mysql-data-stored-on-disk etc etc PS How MySQL stores tables depends on the storage engine. PS Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to know? MySQL has a private algorithm. Other DBMS's have (possibly different) private algorithms. Knowing the algorithm won't help you design 'better' schemas. If you have a query that you think is running slow, ask about that.

Comment: I am not dealing with a specific problem, but understanding how the underlying data structures work would be helpful for determining which database to choose for a given application depending on the most likely data access patterns for that application. Also general intellectual curiousity, I am curious how the underlying data structures support/lend themselves to relational structures.