# Inform other Git contributors of SQL change

Tags: git, github

I'm using GitHub as a project repository, and whenever a contributor changes something in his local database, he sends an email with SQL statements after a pull request to inform all contributors that they must change database before merging the new code source changes.

For example, I can use an issue like this:

1. Create an issue
2. Reference this issue from commit by including
   the issue number inside of commit message.
   Example: `git commit -m "last update, check #13"`

Is there a better way to inform other contributors about SQL changes using Git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bring your database into your repository. Emailing SQL statements around just means they'll get lost. What's the process for a new hire to initialise their database? It's tricky with your current methodology.

This will depend greatly on the language/frameworks/database type you're using.

In practice, it means you commit a series of migration scripts that apply changes to the database in sequential order.

At the most basic level they can be SQL files. If using a more robust tool you can get the option to rollback your changes, rebuild the database schema and so on.

Further reading:

- *[Get Your Database Under Version Control](https://blog.codinghorror.com/get-your-database-under-version-control/)*
- *[Do you use source control for your database items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115369/do-you-use-source-control-for-your-database-items)*