# Database branch as git

Tags: sql, database, version-control

I use workbench to management database, I want to ask there any tool can control version in database like as branch in git?

Answer (score 1):

already had been answered in below thread.

[Do you use source control for your database items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115369/do-you-use-source-control-for-your-database-items)

below blog explained it better.

[Get Your Database Under Version Control](https://blog.codinghorror.com/get-your-database-under-version-control/)