# Deleting a table or a column in phpMyAdmin not using Laravel's options

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

What will happen with my Laravel project if I will manually delete a table or a column in the database using phpMyAdmin? I know the ways how to do that using Laravel's `Schema`, but it feels for me that deleting a column or a table using phpMyAdmin is a much quicker and easier way.

I tried to google it but couldn't find any information about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally good practice to have database changes in source control. You can achieve this by using laravels migrations. It is much harder to keep track of manual changes even if you document them. I assume your are not documenting the changes because it probably wouldn't be quicker.

It probably wont hurt you right now but what if you run multiple databases for multiple environments. Each contributing dev has to make the same changes to their own local environment. The time spend changing them manually quickly grows where as a migration can easily be automated.

It also greatly increases your ability to redeploy your project.

This answer has a must read link about why it is good to have database migrations in source control 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/115382/6242681